# How do I get BASE_URL in Angular SSR?

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I'm currently retrieving the base_url utilizing the following line of code (which I acquired from dotnetcore new solution template):

```
document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0].href
```

This is working fine until I added angular universal as I would like to do some server side rendering. However my project fails to run properly when it encounters my service that attempts to utilize BASE_URL

> NullInjectorError: No provider for BASE_URL!

Can someone please recommend a better way get base_url so I can call my webapi? I should mention that I'm needing this due to the fact that when developing locally my front end is running on port :4200 but my webapi does not use this port so I need to way to detect the port and strip.

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0].href` seems wrong for Angular... And other than that, there isn't any code to see what you are actually doing...

Comment: Can you inject the `BASE_HREF` token instead?

Comment: should mention I ultimately looking for hostname and port.

Comment: Hostname and port of front website? Are you using a reverse proxy such as nginx or apache?

Comment: using ngExpressEngine when developing locally. Everything I have found on stackoverflow has been for older versions of angular. I'm on version 9.